# Prove or disprove that $e^{-x} \, \dfrac{\cos\left( \frac{u-1}{2}\, x\right)}{\cos\left( \frac{u+1}{2}\, x\right)}\geq 1$.

Tags: inequality

Let $u\in[0,1]$. Prove or disprove that there exists an interval $I\subseteq [0,\pi/2]$ for which the following inequality
$$e^{-x} \, \dfrac{\cos\left( \frac{u-1}{2}\, x\right)}{\cos\left( \frac{u+1}{2}\, x\right)}\geq 1$$
is true for $x\in I$.

Comment: When you say "prove that there is an interval", could it not suffice to just find some point $x_*$ and then consider the interval $[x_*, x_*]$ or must the interval necessarily contain distinct endpoints

Comment: $x=\pi/2$ definitely holds.. for all $u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even think a rigorous proof is really needed with this one. I think it suffices to know that  $0\leq$ |$\cos\left( \frac{u-1}{2}\, x\right)$|$\leq$ 1, on [0,$\frac{\pi}{2}$]and that on all $\mathbb R$,|$e^{-x}$|$\geq$ 0 and $e^{-x}\rightarrow$ 0 as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $e^{-x}\rightarrow +\infty$ as  $x\rightarrow -\infty$. So consider

$$e^{-x} \, \dfrac{\cos\left( \frac{u-1}{2}\, x\right)}{\cos\left( \frac{u+1}{2}\, x\right)}\geq 1$$

$\rightarrow $

$$e^{-x} {\cos\left( \frac{u-1}{2}\, x\right)}\geq {\cos\left( \frac{u+1}{2}\, x\right)}$$

The maximum of the left hand side of the equation is a positive real multiple of 1, which is clearly greater then or equal to the maximium value of cos on the interval, which is one. This should suffice.

Comment: Thank you. But... why the maximum of the left hand side of the equation is a positive real multiple of 1?

Comment: @Mark Because the real exponential is defined on all the real numbers and the absolute value of cos is bounded at 1 for all values in the domain.